# Mac software to test speakers via microphone?

Tags: audio, speakers

Is there any Mac software that can:

- Play a sound (such as a music or tone track).
- Use the microphone to
  capture the sound and then compare the waveform to ensure the
  speakers were playing it properly

Obviously, doing this will pick up background room sounds. But hopefully, it can show any problems. I think there might be some distortion in my speakers, but it's hard to tell. So having software that can check would be handy!

Answer (score 2):

There are hardware/software calibration systems for accurately diagnosing audio playback - but this isn't on the list of what they can do. They also start at over $100.

Simplify by finding a 'sine sweep' which should be nicely distortion-free & see if you can actually hear distortion. [it will 'buzz' rather than 'sing'.]

See https://www.audiocheck.net/testtones_highdefinitionaudio.php for some free samples. Read the warnings. Untested. [No affiliation]

Hmm… for a consumer system, this might be easier - https://www.audiocheck.net/testtones_sinesweep20-20k.php

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/erdewit/HiFiScan I am trying this python app on Mac with calibrated mic right now.

Comment: That looks interesting [& in fact I'm going to try it out tomorrow] but it doesn't help for the OP. If he's trying to find 'distortion' rather than a mis-aligned EQ curve.